# Javascript variable has random setting values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to get a variable from my controller, and everything is great until I push the returned data into another variable.

Here is my snippet of code

```
$(".event_selector").change(function() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "/get_customer_values",
      type: "GET",
      async:false,
      data: {event_selected: $(".event_selector").val()},
      success: function(data){
        var customer_values = {};
        for (var i in data) {
          //This alert has the correct values
          alert(i + " " + data[i]);
          customer_values[i] = data[i];
        }
      }
    });

    for(var i in customer_values) {
      //This is the alert that shows all the crazy values
      alert("customer_values " + i + " " + customer_values[i]);
    }

    add_customer_values_to_panel(customer_values)

  });
```

The first alert, using i and data[i] is perfect, with all the right values. The second alert using the customer_values hash has values that look like settings, such as:

**KEY    VALUE**

click   function click() { [native code] }

properties  [object HTMLPropertiesCollection]

oncanplaythrough    null

onchange    null

onclick null

oncontextmenu   null

ondblclick  null

ondrag  null

ondragend   null

getAttributeNames   function getAttributeNames() { [native code] }

getAttribute    function getAttribute() { [native code] }

getAttributeNS  function getAttributeNS() { [native code] }

It has at least 100 other values that look like this.

I tried moving the var customer_values initialization to outsite the ajax, but that doesn't work(nothing happens, and the first alert isn't even triggered).

What is going on? Where is that data coming from? Thank you.

Comment: Where do you declare `customer_values`, and how do you initialize it?

Comment: Do you have an html element with `id="customer_values"`? Given the only `customer_values` shown is declared inside the Ajax success callback the second `for` loop *can't* access it, but given that rather than throwing a reference error it appears to be logging properties that html elements have...well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your "customer_values" object is not global, it is defined inside ajax success function...